# Add .net exe file in GAC

Tags: com, exe, .net-assembly, gac

I've a COM callable exe file which is referred in .net applications and VB6 applications. This exe can't run directly by double cliking on it. It'll be referred in projects like a dll, it has public methods and properties and can run this exe from a referred application by calling a public method.
Since this is used in multiple applications I need to add this into GAC, when I add it into GAC it goes to a folder like below,

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL\MY-ASSEMBLY-NAME\v4.0_1.0.0.0__8676d6af9e2465de
```

is it right? expected behavior? Are you seeing any problem in add-in this exe to GAC and using it from multiple applications?

Comment: Well sure it is right, .NET doesn't care about the distinction between DLL and EXE files.  It is whatever you hope to happen next that's bound to be disappointing, COM does care.  Change your project type to "Class library", the only thing that really makes sense.

Comment: I can't have this as class library since it has an executable part. from referring application can call a public method in this exe and this exe will display some UI. That's why I didn't create this as class library.